# Validation of validation valid

Tags: arrays

I'm trying to make Regex for validating
My main problem contains:

So I made something like this

```
(?=^.{10,}$)(?=.*^[a-z])(?![.\n])(?=.[A-Z]{1})([a-z0-9])(?=.*[$@$!%*#?&]{2}).*$
```

Do you have any ideas where I'm wrong? I tought that with `{1}` I will make it functionate but apparently I was wrong.

Comment: Your third and fourth conditions are crazy.

Comment: Do specials has to be successive?

Comment: @Redu They dont need to be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The actual regex:

```
(?=^[a-z])
(?=^[^A-Z]*[A-Z]{1}[^A-Z]*$)
(?=^[^$@$!%*#?&]*[$@$!%*#?&][^$@$!%*#?&]*[$@$!%*#?&][^$@$!%*#?&]*$)
^.{10,}$
```

Put it in one line for `JavaScript`.

#### Explanation:

- `(?=^[a-z])` - make sure the first letter is a lowercase one
- `(?=^[^A-Z]*[A-Z]{1}[^A-Z]*$)` - this monster says from the start (`^`) to the end (`$`) make sure to find 0 or more characters which are not `A-Z`, then one of `A-Z`, then the first pattern again. This makes effectively sure to only match **one** uppercase character in the string
- `(?=[^$@$!%*#?&]*[$@$!%*#?&]{2}[^$@$!%*#?&]*)` - the same mechanism as with the uppercase letters
- `^.{10,}$` make sure to match at least 10 characters and bind the string to the beginning and the end

As pointed out by [@Shafizadeh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2805376/shafizadeh), the requirements are funny, though.

#### Demo:

See a [demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/zV0dJ2/4).

Comment: Hah .. Great answer for funny question `:-)` +1

Comment: FYI, you have to replace `{10}` with `{10,}`, according to first OP's condition: *Need to have **at least** 10 characters*

Comment: @Shafizadeh: Right you are, fixed.

Comment: @Superbrain_bug: I thought, *at least* two special characters - it's because of the *not A-Z part*.

Comment: No,no, I mixed something... I tought it's clear if I say "two" specials... Sry .. But, can u explain me than why {2} wont work for 2 specials only

Comment: @Superbrain_bug: One moment, I'll add an explanation to my answer.

Comment: BTW, in your pattern those two specials should be continuous and I think it's not OP wants. please edit it too `:-)`

Comment: Yeah, they dont need to be, I made it like that, but they dont need to be

Comment: @Shafizadeh: Updated the answer.

Comment: @Jan Thank you very much!

Comment: Cool pattern however i understand that since the characters like `;",.:;~<>'-+[]{}()/` which aren't listed as special characters shall be omitted. Available characters should be limited to 0-9 A-Z a-z and the given specials. Well of course OP should know better. I have excluded them in my solution.

Answer (score 0):

This was a tough one to crack. But i guess the following is all fine.

```
(?=[a-z][0-9A-Za-z$@!%*#?&]+)
(?!(.*[$@!%*#?&]){3,})(?=(.*[$@!%*#?&]){2})
(?!(.*[A-Z]){2,})(?=(.*[A-Z]))
.{10,}$
```

First line is in charge of setting both the first character to be lowercase and limiting the whole pattern to certain characters. So inclusion of unwanted special characters like `;<>'-+[]{}()/` etc will disable the selection

Second line is in charge of limiting the special character count to less than 3 and 2 or more condition.

Third line is in charge of limiting the capital letter count to less than 2 and 1 or more condition.

Fourth line is of course giving the total minimum character count as 10.